# NX With Angular and Nest: package.json treeshaking

Tags: angular, nestjs

So let's assume I have an NX monorepo with 2 apps: Angular and Nest. Since it is a monorepo it has a common package.json file with dependencies, both for client and server. The question is simple: will my Angular's bundle contain Nest dependencies and vice versa? In other words, is there is some kind of treeshaking so the unused code is removed from the final bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the built in `ng` functionality, that all deals with webpacking and tree-shaking your code, so it will not cross your angular dependencies with your Nest ones, unless they are needed. This works with `ng build` and espeically with the `--prod` flag.

Note: webpacking the server is a little weird, as it does mean your entire server runs from one file, which is a bit different in the node world, but it is still doable.

Comment: Cool! But how about Angular deps in NestJS bundle?

Comment: So long as you `ng build api` or whatever your nest project is called, then it shouldn't happen. If you use typescript to manually build your server then yes, but usually server bubndle size is not as cared about

Comment: to get a single js file for your node project, you can use: https://github.com/vercel/ncc